# Elasticsearch - retrieve specific fields also based on conditions

Tags: rest, elasticsearch

We are storing information coming from an external system in Elastic, since the JSON structure is quite dynamic and we want to be able to perform searches on it. The requirement I have is to create an excel template based on the data retrieved from Elastic.

Now I know I can use **_source** or **fields** options in the API query body to retrieve only certain elements based on their JSON path, but is there a way to also provide conditions. What I mean by conditions is for example we have multilanguage fields (see below) which have same JSON path, but I only want to retrieve the german value.

```
"functionalNames": [
            {
                "languageCode": "de-DE",
                "value": "DE value"
            },
            {
                "languageCode": "fr-BE",
                "value": "FR value"
            },
            {
                "languageCode": "nl-BE",
                "value": "NL value"
            }
        ]
```

Also, we would also like to do some calculations, like transforming centimeters in meters, grams in kgs etc. I guess that can be done using the **script_fields** option, but I'll have to check more on it.

Thanks

I was using something like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "ids": {
            "values": [
                "id1",
                "id2",
                "id3",
                "id4"
            ]
        }
    },
    "fields": [
        "functionalNames.value",
        "JSONAttributePath1",
        "JSONAttributePath2"
    ],
    "_source": false
}
```

But I don't know how to apply conditions. If I use the "language-code = de-DE" in the **query** parameter, I'm worried some results that don't even have this data in the index might not be retrieved, so it's not an option.

Comment: I think you need to use `search template`, [have a look the following](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html)

Comment: Yes, maybe that's one thing to do, now I'm struggling with creating this search query, especially since my JSON is quite dynamic. Sometimes I have a single object in a parameter, other times an array. I don't know how to always convert that to an array, because my parser fails otherwise

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking to perform a query, as you mention applying *conditions*.

Here's an example of how to search for German documents:

```
POST my-index-name/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "languageCode": "de-DE"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried, the issue with this is that even a query like languageCode = "de-DE" and value = "NL value" is valid and returns the document

Comment: @BogdanBoglea in that case, could you update the question with an example of one of your documents? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding.